# What is AppCompat theme and can I change it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

I'm new to Android Studio. Not long ago I mentioned that the "AppCompat.NoActionBar" theme fits so well on my application, but soon I realized that I want to change its primary gray color. I've already set up some color resources for this.
My question is how do I redefine AppCompat primary colors and is it even a good solution (and is it even possible)? For now, I just want to change my app background color to something that I already have in my colors.xml file as "bg_lighter_gray".
What I do know is that I can use `android:background` property to change the color on each activity, but is there a way for them to be inherited by the app's theme so I won't have to define the background color manually every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem I've added one additional item in `themes.xml`:

```
    <style name="Theme.ThemeTest" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/colorOnPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `themes.xml` (or `styles.xml`) you can define your themes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>

</style>
```

Then you can apply it to your application using:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

or just one activity:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still haven't figured it out. Is "colorPrimary" a predefined name? When I change its value, nothing actually happens to my application. Even though I apply my custom theme in the manifest.

Comment: @PapkaScallom Yes, it is a built-in attribute used by the widgets. Check more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes